# Can I use BSD sockets in Android NDK?

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk, native, cellular-network

I thought I'd ask this here first because setting up anything with the NDK is such a pain. I know Android uses the Linux kernel but I know little of it's POSIX compliance as far as C libraries. **Does the Android OS family implement the BSD socket API?**

And if it does implement BSD sockets, am I allowed to simply implement a TCP/IP socket per `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM` or must I do something else to account for cellular protocols like 4G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is Linux.  So yes, you can use normal sockets and Unix API calls.  Where there's platform specific behavior, it should follow how Linux does things.

Comment: Ok that's good to know. I was only aware that it used the Linux kernel. Do you know if I have to do anything differently to handle 1x, 2G, 3G, 4G, and LTE protocols? Or will the OS do that for me?

Comment: OS should do that for you, its at a lower level of abstraction than sockets.  Although you may see disconnects if you're in an area where you keep losing one speed and dropping to a lower tier.